# If a DES key correctly decrypts one message, what's the probability it's the real key?

Tags: des

Suppose an adversary gets a message-ciphertext pair $(M,C)$, where $C=DES_K(M)$. They do an exhaustive key reach to locate the lexicographically first key $T$ for which $C=DES_T(M)$.  What's the probability that $T=K$?

Comment: Is $M$ one block long, or longer? If longer, what mode of operation is used?

Comment: Hint: if DES was an ideal cipher, $X\to DES_X(M)$ would behave like a random function, Using this, estimate odds that there exists no $T$ less than $K$, as a function of the value of $K$; then that expected odd for random $K$; then what's asked.